# Python different operations on the same resources

Tags: python, multithreading, file, queue

I'm trying to analyze a large python file with different tasks on it. I've already read and preprocessed the file and it's now in memory. The thing is, the tasks I have, they pretty much have to go through the whole list of the records. It's something similar like:

```
resourceList = [..] #list of records from the file (say, 2GB)
def taskA():
    for i in resourceList:
        #doSthA()

def taskB():
    for i in resourceList:
        #doSthB()
```

If I do taskA() then taskB() it's going through the 2GB file twice and it's really slow. Is that a way that taskA and taskB can do their job simultaneously at the same time so that I don't have to go through the task twice?

I read about something which involved python threads and Queue, is that the only (and right) way to do it? If so, what if the "resourceList" is a generator instead of a list?

Thanks!

Comment: you can feed the same list to two `multiprocessing` processes

Comment: Are the two functions share common data which could change during the course of execution ?

Comment: @anmol_uppal I don't think so, but they each will yield something after computation based on the list contents

Comment: can you write your `taskA` and `taskB` so that they each operate on a single record?  then just `for rec in ResourceList: taskA(rec);taskB(rec)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement this using threading (because I find this problem easier to reason about when each task is a separate thread, and threading over multiprocessing so that data can be shared), then passing each function a queue which can be iterated over:

```
import threading
from Queue import Queue

class IterableQueue(Queue): 
    _sentinel = object()

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.get, self._sentinel)

    def close(self):
        self.put(self._sentinel)

def taskA(resources):
    for resource in resources:
        do_stuff()

def taskB(resources):
    for resource in resources:
        do_stuff()

def start_thread(task):
    queue = IterableQueue(maxsize=1)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=task, args=(queue, ))
    thread.start()
    return (thread, queue)

threads = [
    start_thread(taskA),
    start_thread(taskB),
]

resource_list = [...]

for resource in resource_list:
    for _, queue in threads:
        queue.put(resource)

for thread, _ in threads:
    thread.join()
```